# Certificates in Kubernetes, OpenShift and AWS EKS as non-root

Tags: docker, kubernetes

I am adding support to Kubernetes, OpenShift and EKS to a native Docker application. It's a classic .net application with kestrel.

Two steps are essential in our current design:

1. We have our own CA, that I trust during start (docker exec -u root update-ca-certificates).
2. Customers can add their certificates to a volume that is mounted when image runs. The application is set to read the certificates from that path.

I created a custom image that runs update-ca-certificates via Dockerfile, so the first problem is solved.

However:

1. Without being able to run as root (and remain compliant to best practices), how can I get my clients to be able to upload their certificates to the application?
2. If the customer has their own MSSQL cluster with a self-signed certificate, then my application will refuse connecting to it. How could I have the customer's CA trusted assuming that I wouldn't be able to execute commands as root?

I am happy to overhaul the whole process if the solution is "out-of-the-box".

## Thanks, as always.

Comment: You said that, "Customers can add their certificates to a volume that is mounted when image runs". You mean that is a capability they already have, or something you are trying to implement? If the former, the fact that, "The application is set to read the certificates from that path" makes it seem like this is a solved problem. I may just be misreading something?

Comment: @larsks We have the capability now, but I cant figure out how to support it in an environment where operators may not be able to mount volumes or do anything as root. For example, they wouldnt be able to touch cert folders.